# Isinstance returning incorrect answer

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following variable:

`ar` with the value `datetime.date(2000, 3, 1)`

However when I try to check if it is datetime, like so `isinstance(ar, datetime)` it returns False.

How is that possible? When I try `type(ar)`, I get `<class 'datetime.date'>`

Comment: `datetime` is the module containing the class but it isn't the base class.

Comment: Did you mean : `isinstance(start_date_br, datetime.date)`?

Comment: It helps to have a fully working example for things like this. But note that `datetime.date` is not a subclass of `datetime.datetime` so it should be `False`.

Comment: And to note, if OP were accidentally referencing the `datetime` module, it would be a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not referencing the datetime module correctly when using isinstance, here is the correct use:

```
import datetime

ar = datetime.date(2000, 3, 1)

print(isinstance(ar, datetime.date)) # prints True
```

If you were to check if ar is an instance of datetime.datetime:

```
print(isinstance(ar, datetime.datetime))  # This should print False, as ar is not a datetime object
```

Comment: `isinstance` on a module raises a TypeError so its not that.

Comment: @tdelaney not too sure if you've ran this code but this is working perfectly for me. print(isinstance(ar, datetime.date)) returns True, print(isinstance(ar, datetime.datetime)) returns False

Comment: @tdelaney see image -> https://imgur.com/a/kqD1sCU

Comment: "You are probably not referencing the datetime module correctly" - suggests that OP is referencing the `datetime` module in `isinstance`. My note addresses that ambiguity.